# terminology for Unicode characters outside the ASCII range

Tags: unicode, terminology

Is there an accepted terminology for referring to the Unicode characters that are above the ASCII range (above code point 127 decimal)?

I have seen these called "extended ASCII" and "Unicode characters", neither of which is satisfactory.

("Extended ASCII" is not well-defined, wrongly implies an "extension" to the ASCII standard, and in any event has historically only referred to characters up to 255 decimal, not the entire Unicode range. "Unicode" implies that ASCII characters are NOT Unicode, which is false)

Comment: Code points U+00000 through U+0007F are called the "[Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block))" block. So you could call the other characters "not Basic Latin". The block was formerly called "ASCII" so you could say that the other characters are "non-ASCII".

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

The 144,697 characters in Unicode are organized into [dozens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block#List_of_blocks) of logical groupings known as *blocks*.

The 128 characters defined in the legacy encoding [US-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) are known in Unicode as the [*Basic Latin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block) block. Unicode is a superset of US-ASCII.

So no, there is no special name for the other 144,569 of 144,697 characters. If you mean *Thai* characters, those are found in the [Thai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_(Unicode_block)) block. If you mean the *Cherokee* characters, those are found in the [Cherokee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherokee_(Unicode_block)) block. And so on.

## Details

[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) defines 144,697 characters, each assigned a number referred to as a [*code point*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). The code point numbers range from zero to over a million (1,114,112 decimal or 10FFFF hex), most being reserved or unassigned.

Those characters are grouped logically into a range of code points known as a [*block*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block). The [US-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters make up the [*Basic Latin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) block in Unicode, the first 128 code points, with Unicode being a superset of US-ASCII.

The next 128 code points, U+0080 to U+00FF, is known as the [*Latin-1 Supplement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)).

You will find dozens more [blocks listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block#List_of_blocks). For example, Greek and Coptic, Cyrillic, [Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)), Samaritan, Bengali, Tibetan, [Arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block)), [Braille Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_Patterns), [Chess Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_Symbols), and many more. If curious, browse a [history of the blocks](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Versions) added to versions of Unicode.

You asked:

> Is there an accepted terminology for referring to the Unicode characters that are above the ASCII range (above code point 127 decimal)?

No official term that I know of. Some might say “non-ASCII”. Personally, I would say “beyond US-ASCII", with the word “beyond” referring to the number range higher than 127 decimal.

You said:

> I have seen these called "extended ASCII" and "Unicode characters", neither of which is satisfactory.

The label [“extended ASCII”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) is unofficial, ambiguous, and unhelpful. The term usually refers to the positions 0 to 255 decimal in various pre-Unicode [8-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_computing) [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). There are many "extended ASCII" encodings. So I suggest you avoid this term when discussing Unicode. I believe that in 2022 we can consider all of those "extended ASCII" encodings to be [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system).

As for “Unicode characters”, all 144,697 characters defined in Unicode are “Unicode characters” including the 128 characters of US-ASCII. (Again, Unicode is a superset of US-ASCII.) So referring to any subset of those 144,697 characters as “Unicode characters” is silly and unhelpful.

---

As an American myself, I have to say I note a bias in the Question. It appears to me that many Americans in the information technology industry carry a bias that somehow US-ASCII characters, containing the alphabet of basic American English, are “normal” and all other characters are “foreign” or “weird”. This view misses the very reason that Unicode was invented: To *put all scripts around the world on an equal footing*, all accounted for in a single set of code point assignments, all documented together in identical fashion by a single authoritative organization, and all implemented with the same technology.

So I suggest adjusting your thinking. Rather than attempting to bifurcate Unicode into ASCII & non-ASCII, learn to think in terms of [the dozens of Unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block#List_of_blocks). When dealing with legacy systems that use only US-ASCII, know that the *Basic Latin* block of Unicode corresponds. This block is no more or less important than any other block.

Most every modern operating system today supports Unicode, thankfully. That support means *all* of Unicode, never a subset. Regarding subsets, the only limit is fonts. No one font contains glyphs for every one of the 144,697 characters defined in Unicode. So most fonts focus on only a few or several of the many blocks.

---

For those learning about these topics, I highly recommend the article [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky. You may find it to be a surprisingly entertaining read.

Comment: I agree that there is a "bias in the question" but it is not simply a cultural bias but a technical one.  While it's true that "every modern operating system today supports Unicode", software is a lot more than just operating systems. "Legacy software" (as well as "sub-optimal design") is a fact of life.  If my software relies on another piece of software, and that software only accepts ASCII, I have no choice but to somehow prevent "non-ASCII" characters from being sent to that other software.  And if I want to document that limitation, I need the terminology to do so.